# Get variable based on function argument?

Tags: javascript

HTML:

```
<button id="s01" onclick="getMusic(this.id)"></button>
<button id="s02" onclick="getMusic(this.id)"></button>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var s01 = ["file", "song"];
var s02 = ["file", "song"];

function getMusic(e){
    alert()
}
```

Alright so I have this code above (This is a simplified version). This function will set `e` in `getMusic(e)` to either `s01` or `s02`. I need to be able to call the variable that corresponds to that name (within the `alert()`) but I'm not even sure where to start. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

---

P.S. any chance I can remove the `onclick=""` from the HTML file and replace it with an `addEventListener` in the js file and still achieve the same effect? I don't like mixing my scripts like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use an object to hold your data, it's a lot easier

```
var data = {
   s01 : ["file", "song"],
   s02 : ["file", "song"]
};

function getMusic(e){
    console.log(  data[e]  );
}
```

If you use `addEventListener` you can remove the inline javascript as well

```js
var data = {
  s01 : ["file1", "song"],
  s02 :["file2", "song"]
}

document.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log( data[this.id] );
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="s01" class="btn">Test 1</button>
<button id="s02" class="btn">Test 1</button>
```

Comment: OP does not need to change his data type. The built-in `window` object presents this data in exactly the same way, i.e. `window["s01"]`.

Comment: @Toastrackenigma - That's why I suggest using an object, adding globals, and assuming the variables are in fact global, is bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

First off, to answer your second question, yes, you can register the event listener in your JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]").forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener("click", getMusic)
})
```

Once you have your event handler registered that way, you can get the `id` of the button by accessing `e.target.id`.

```
function getMusic(e){
  alert(e.target.id) // will alert with button id
}
```

At this point, you have a string containing the `id`; now you need to be able to pull the values that correspond to the `id`. It makes the most sense to defined a JSON bag with hashes corresponding to `id`.

```
var data = {
  s01: ["your", "data"],
  s02: ["your", "other", "data"]
}
function getMusic(e){
  myData = data[e.target.id]
  alert(myData)
}
```

Comment: There are at least two problems with your answer. Firstly, you can't call `addEventListener` on a nodeList, and secondly, `e.target` isn't neccessarely the element bound in the handler.

Comment: yep, noticed those issues as well. thanks for the heads up. edited.

Answer (score -2):

In JavaScript, the `window` object exists, which contains all global variables.

Simply use `window[e]` to get your array's value:

```js
var s01 = ["file", "song"];
var s02 = ["file", "song"];

function getMusic(e){
    alert(window[e])
}
```

```html
<button id="s01" onclick="getMusic(this.id)"></button>
<button id="s02" onclick="getMusic(this.id)"></button>
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? `window` is the supported way to do this in JavaScript.

Comment: [Global variables are bad news.](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad) Just because you _can_, doesn't mean you _should_.